# Is there a more eloquent way of programming this method?

Tags: java, object, methods

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodWalkthrough {
    private static int num = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean stringHasI = true;

        while(stringHasI){
            String testString = kb.next();   //String to test
            char testCh = kb.next().charAt(0);   //char to determine how many instances it appears in testString
            numI(testString,testCh);
            if(num==0)
                stringHasI = false;
            num=0;

        }

    }

    public static int numI(String test, char testChar){

        for(int i = 0;i<test.length();i++){
            if(test.charAt(i)==testChar)
                num++;
        }
        System.out.println("There are "+num+" "+testChar+"'s in "+test);
        return num;

    }
}
```

I want to actually utilize the returned value, "num", but whenever I try to reference it when it is in the method, it is not in the scope of the main method.  So my workaround was to make it a "public static int".  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You don't even use the return value of the function `numI`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your method returns `int`, you simply need to assign an `int` in your `main` method with the value returned by `numI`.

For instance:

```
int result = numI(testString,testCh);
```

That implies removing the `static int num` declaration from your class, and initializing and returning an `int` within the `numI` method scope.

For instance (inside `numI`):

```
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0;i<test.length();i++){
...
// TODO assign/increment/print "result" instead of former "num"
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

num global declaration is useless and numI method could be improved, here is a compact example :

```
public static int numI(String test, char testChar)
{
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; (i = test.indexOf(testChar, i) + 1) != 0; num++);
    return num;
}
```

Usage :

```
while(stringHasI)
{
    String testString = kb.next();   //String to test
    char testCh = kb.next().charAt(0);   //char to determine how many instances it appears in testString
    int num = numI(testString,testCh);
    stringHasI = num != 0;
}
```